# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: at \b within regexp

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to validate a phone number in the format;  xxx-nnn-yyyy
The following message is issued and I can't figure out why it does not work. Ii seems that \b is in error. Thanks for any help/suggestion/correction/direction to where a similar issue is described as I couldn't find any so far.

```
    /AndroidRuntime(3143): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 6:
    /AndroidRuntime(3143): ^\\(?([0-9]{3})\\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})
    /AndroidRuntime(3143):       ^
    /AndroidRuntime(3143):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)

    temp = phone.getText().toString();
    if (temp.length() == 0)  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone number is missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Matching Phone Short");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\\\(?\b([0-9]{3})\\\\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})\b"); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(temp) ;
    if (m.find()){
    Log.i("RC OK", "ret code GOOD");    
    }else{
    Log.i("RC NOK", "ret code BAD");    
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\\\(?\b([0-9]{3})\\\\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})\b");
```

Since there is no valid identifier after `(?`, also `\b` should be `\\b`

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\\\(?:\\b([0-9]{3})\\\\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})\\b");
```